# Retrieving Process Description Information

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to retrieve process information and I'm aware that I can use:

```
Process[] myProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
```

but how do I retrieve the process description?  Is it via some Win32 API call?  I'm running Vista and when I click under the Processes tab in Task Manager, I see the description.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you see in Task Manager is actually the Description field of the executable image.

You can use the `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` WinAPI calls to access various version informations, e.g. CompanyName or FileDescription.

For .Net way, use the `FileDescription` member of `FileVersionInfo`, instantiated with the executable name got via `Process.MainModule.FileName`.

Another way would be through `Assembly`. Load the Assembly from the executable image, then query the `AssemblyDescriptionAttribute`  custom attribute.

Answer (score 12):

You just have to go a bit further down the properties.
Suppose you have an instance of notepad running.

```
Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
Console.WriteLine("Process version- " + proc[0].MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
Console.WriteLine("Process description- " + proc[0].MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription);
```

There you go !

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I could see to do it.  I tried Process and Win32_Process, but no go.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Management
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ps = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (var p in ps)
            {
                try
                {
                    var desc = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    Console.WriteLine(desc.FileDescription);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Access Denied");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```