# How to get the description of a running process on a remote machine?

Tags: c#, process, wmi, remote-access

I have tried two ways to accomplish this so far.

The first way, I used `System.Diagnostics`, but I get a `NotSupportedException` of "Feature is not supported for remote machines" on the `MainModule`.

```
foreach (Process runningProcess in Process.GetProcesses(server.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(runningProcess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription);
}
```

The second way, I attempted using `System.Management` but it seems that the `Description` of the `ManagementObject` is the she same as the `Name`.

```
string scope = @"\\" + server.Name + @"\root\cimv2";
string query = "select * from Win32_Process";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj["Name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(obj["Description"].ToString());
}
```

Would anyone happen to know of a better way to go about getting the descriptions of a running process on a remote machine?

Comment: Have you tried using Rob van der Woude's wmigen? It might help show what's available. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmigen.php

Comment: @Lizz Well I've already tried looping through the properties of obj and checked to see if the Property.ToString() contained a keyword that should have been in the description of one of the processes that I'm searching for...

Comment: Yikes. Sorry, can't think of anything else. :( This is interesting - and odd. +1 for good code and troubleshooting! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192046/retrieving-process-description-information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I think I've got a method of doing this that will work well enough for my purposes.  I'm basically getting the file path off of the `ManagementObject` and getting the description from the actual file.

```
ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Username = "username";
connection.Password = "password";
connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + serverName + @"\root\cimv2", connection);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_Process");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    if (obj["ExecutablePath"] != null)
    {
        string processPath = obj["ExecutablePath"].ToString().Replace(":", "$");
        processPath = @"\\" + serverName + @"\" + processPath;

        FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(processPath);
        string processDesc = info.FileDescription;
    }
}
```