# how to get application name using .exe in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

[image]I am new in C#, I want to get the application name (Which is displaying in task manger app part) using .exe.

I have googled it but didn't found useful information.

I want to Description information for each exe.

Thanks,

Comment: You can maybe be more specific.
If you want to get the app name it's like this post with : `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829689/how-to-get-exe-application-name-and-version-in-c-sharp-compact-framework

Comment: That will provide your application executable name. I want all application name which is currently running.

Comment: I think that this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/648413/2599868

`using System.Diagnostics;
...
var allProcceses = Process.GetProcesses();`
Then get the name or any other information from that object

Comment: I have put snapshot in question. I want to get descrption information for each exe.

Comment: I have put snapshot for my question . Now you will understand better. What you are saying, we will get process name. I want description of each exe. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Process Description Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192046/retrieving-process-description-information)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class located under `System.Diagnostics` :

`using System.Diagnostics;
...
var allProcceses = Process.GetProcesses();
//loop throught processes
string process_description= process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;`

This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/648413/2599868) provides some information about the `Process` class.

NB : you may have some issues when trying to access some processes running under SYSTEM credentials : see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672044/how-to-get-the-process-description-based-on-process-idc-net).